# Can't download image in Android

Tags: java, android, android-glide

In my Asynctask's onPostExecute method

```
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylinlay);
TextView tv=new TextView(Download_İmage.this);
tv.setText("try");
ImageView tempimg=new ImageView(Download_İmage.this);
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg").into(tempimg);
tv.setCompoundDrawables(tempimg.getDrawable(),null,null,null);
ll.addView(tv);
```

here adding all textview to linearlayout dynamically.All textviews with text looks ok and also tried with existed drawable image its working.But when i try to download image via picasso or glide its not working.So i cant get remote image.

**com.bumptech.glide.Glide failed lock verification and will run slower.**
Have this message and same message for picasso as well.I am checked with debug option but that image drawable getting null.

Comment: What version of Glide are you using?

Comment: first add your 'ImageView' to linearlayout then try loading with glide or picasso

Comment: compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2' tried this and  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0' this

Comment: But sir i have to add imageview to my textview via setCompoundDrawables

Answer (score 1):

After a quick Google, the only result that shows the same problem is this [closed issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1393) on Glide's GitHub.

Apparently, this error exists in older versions of Glide, but has been fixed in 2017. You should update your Glide version to the latest (currently 4.6.1):

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
```

And in your project's `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}
```

Comment: Sir i have added got this  Error:Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:_debugAnnotationProcessor' after it has been resolved.Btw my gradle online not offline.

Answer (score 0):

you should use glide like this.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load("someurl")
                    .placeholder("your_placeHolder")
                    .fitCenter()
                    .error("your_errorImg")
                    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Same outcome sir.Ty anyway